# Query to get flag for existed value

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

i want to know whether particular course is there in particular institute or not ,
  I have 3 Institutions

here is my table with data for courses under institution

```
Course_types
unique_id,course_id,course_name,institution_id
1         1          economics  1
2         1          economics  2
3         1          economics  3
4         2          Science    1
5         2          Science    3
```

The Desired output is something like

```
course_id,course_name,inst_1,inst_2,inst_3 

1        economics     yes    yes    yes
2        Science       yes    No      yes
```

I have tried pivoting but it yeilds th count under one institution but i am unable to set flag as 'yes' or 'No'

Thanks for any help

here is what i have tried

```
select   course_id,course_name,

max(decode(institution_id, '1' ,'yes','no')) inst_1 ,

max( decode(institution_id, '2' ,'yes','no')) inst_2,

max(decode(pt.institution_id, '3' ,'yes','no')) inst_3,
from course_types
group by course_id,course_name
```

Comment: hi dasblinkenlight  i have added how i tried

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work, with the exception of the `pt.` table alias (which I'm guessing is a typo).  The following fixes the table alias problem and removes the quotes from the constant numbers (I'm guessing `institution_id` is numeric):

```
select course_id, course_name,
       max(decode(institution_id, 1, 'yes', 'no')) as inst_1 ,
       max(decode(institution_id, 2, 'yes', 'no')) as inst_2,
       max(decode(institution_id, 3, 'yes', 'no')) as inst_3,
from course_types
group by course_id, course_name;
```

How does this fail?